# Invoking a Saba java web service using PHP and SOAP

Tags: java, php, curl, soap

I'm currently developing a way to use the "Forgot your password" function in Saba in conjunction with SSO but without being on the Saba website directly.

I've encountered a problem when trying to access the Saba web service and am currently at a brick wall.

the var_dump error that i'm getting is the following:

```
string(544) " ns1:Server.NoService The AXIS engine could not find a target service to invoke! targetService is InfoService/cspsRetrievePassword "
```

Here are the details:

Saba is built in a way that we can't use REST on custom web service, only SOAP.
I'm calling the following function on form submit:

```
public function doPasswordRetrieval($pId, $pAction, $pNewPassword, $pOldPassword, $pIsOldPasswordHashed, $pSecretQ, $pSecretA, $pSendMail){
    if($this->isAuthenticated()) {

        $soapenv = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
        $soapcommand = 'cspsRetrievePassword';
        $soapurl = "https://mydomain/axis/services/InfoService";
        $soapcert = $this->getCertificate();
        $soapqryid = $pId;
        $soapqryact = $pAction;
        $soapqrynewp = $pNewPassword;
        $soapqryoldp = $pOldPassword;
        $soapqryphash = $pIsOldPasswordHashed;
        $soapqrysecq = $pSecretQ;
        $soapqryseca = $pSecretA;
        $soapqrymail = $pSendMail;


        $soapqry = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="' . $soapenv . '">';
        $soapqry .= '<SOAP-ENV:Body>';
        $soapqry .= '<saba:' . $soapcommand . ' xmlns:saba="' . $soapurl . '">';
        $soapqry .= '<certificate>' . $soapcert . '</certificate>';
        $soapqry .= '<id>' . $soapqryid . '</id>';
        $soapqry .= '<action>' . $soapqryact . '</action>';
        $soapqry .= '<newPass>' . $soapqrynewp . '</newPass>';
        $soapqry .= '<oldPass>' . $soapqryoldp . '</oldPass>';
        $soapqry .= '<isOldPasswordHashed>' . $soapqryphash . '</isOldPasswordHashed>';
        $soapqry .= '<secretQuestion>' . $soapqrysecq . '</secretQuestion>';
        $soapqry .= '<secretAnswer>' . $soapqryseca . '</secretAnswer>';
        $soapqry .= '<sendMail>' . $soapqrymail . '</sendMail>';
        $soapqry .= '</saba:' . $soapcommand . '>';
        $soapqry .= '</SOAP-ENV:Body>';
        $soapqry .= '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

        $url = $soapurl . '/' . $soapcommand;
        $headers = array(
                    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                    "Accept: text/xml",
                    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                    "Pragma: no-cache",
                    "SOAPAction: " . $url, 
                    "Content-length: " . strlen($soapqry),
                );


        $handle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10000);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soapqry);

        $response = curl_exec($handle);
        curl_close($handle);

        var_dump($response);
        //return $response;
    }
}
```

The SOAP wrapper and XML could be written differently instead of adding to a string but i'm currently in dev and only trying to make it work.

My first reaction is that the web service does not exist, but it does.

In saba, web service section:

```
Name* cspsRetrievePassword
Java Class* csps.CspsRetrievePasswordCommand
```

I can paste my custom java class if needed, but the main parts are all presents

```
public class CspsRetrievePasswordCommand extends SabaWebCommand

public CspsRetrievePasswordCommand()
    throws SabaException
{

    addInParam("id", String.class, " person id");
    addInParam("action", String.class, "action value");
    addInParam("newPass", String.class, " new password ");
    addInParam("oldPass", String.class, " old password ");
    addInParam("isOldPasswordHashed", String.class, " is old password in hashed format");
    addInParam("secretQuestion", String.class, " secret question");
    addInParam("secretAnswer", String.class, " secret answer");
    addInParam("sendMail", String.class, " send Mail?");
}

public void doExecute(HttpServletRequest request, IXMLVisitor visitor)
```

My second reaction was that the $url syntax is incorrect.

I tried the following with no luck:

- /axis/services/InfoService/cspsRetrievePassword
- /axis/services/InfoService?cspsRetrievePassword
- /axis/services/InfoService

The last one, calling the web service without having the command inside the URL, and only inside the SOAP query gave me a different error:

```
string(436) " (70034) Exception in executing info service: @001 java.lang.NullPointerException "
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer to my problem.

The first thing to do is simply to add a  element to the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

$soapqry should be the following:  (notice the < query >)

```
        $soapqry = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="' . $soapenv . '">';
        $soapqry .= '<SOAP-ENV:Body>';
        $soapqry .= '<saba:' . $soapcommand . ' xmlns:saba="' . $soapurl . '">';
        $soapqry .= '<certificate>' . $soapcert . '</certificate>';
        $soapqry .= '<query>';
        $soapqry .= '<id>' . $soapqryid . '</id>';
        $soapqry .= '<action>' . $soapqryact . '</action>';
        $soapqry .= '<newPass>' . $soapqrynewp . '</newPass>';
        $soapqry .= '<oldPass>' . $soapqryoldp . '</oldPass>';
        $soapqry .= '<isOldPasswordHashed>' . $soapqryphash . '</isOldPasswordHashed>';
        $soapqry .= '<secretQuestion>' . $soapqrysecq . '</secretQuestion>';
        $soapqry .= '<secretAnswer>' . $soapqryseca . '</secretAnswer>';
        $soapqry .= '<sendMail>' . $soapqrymail . '</sendMail>';
        $soapqry .= '</query>';
        $soapqry .= '</saba:' . $soapcommand . '>';
        $soapqry .= '</SOAP-ENV:Body>';
        $soapqry .= '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';
```

Second is to make sure the CURLOPT_URL is only the /infoservice url, without the command

```
$url = "https://mydomain/axis/services/InfoService";
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

Third is to set the SOAPAction in the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER to the command itself, without the url

```
$headers = array(
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
    "Accept: text/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "SOAPAction: " . $soapcommand, 
    "Content-length: " . strlen($soapqry)
);
```

Hopefully that will help other people on how to use SABA web service with PHP